# How to prevent scaling of images on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

I've been having a lot of issues with displaying images on mobile devices. It has something to do with pixel ratios and scaling.

The idea is that I want to prevent billiniar filtering on my images. On desktop this is easy, just display the image at 1x, and it looks perfect.

There are some issues with desktop, such as when you try to scale up using the browser it filters the image, but you can at least upload a scaled version and it will look perfect.

Here is my test page: http://stage.samkeddy.com/test/

You can see that all but the second one are perfectly crisp.

But here is what it looks like on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9kaT.jpg

It's not even close to the right size. The image should be 70 pixels wide, but it comes out to either 53 or 63 pixels wide (one is page loaded, second is after double tapping).

I want my image to line up exactly with the pixels on my phone, is there a way to even achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should forget pixel in mobile device, like android, the screen density is barely same, a picture looks different at different density screen.

I suggest using some responsive design, use min-width parameter for a img tag, and the image from server side should big enough to prevent blur.

There are also some image service which provide scale function, you can add ?w=100&h=100 to thre image url for compressing a big picture to a small one.

Comment: Problem is I'm trying to display pixel art, which can only be scaled using nearest neighbor, it can't look blurry.

Comment: @stackers Oh, that's a different problem. Have you try initial-scale=1?